# How would I add a counter to this elevator?

Tags: java

I want to add a counter that would count towards the floor the user wants to go to. For example if the user wants to go to floor 7 it would output "2 3 4 5 6 7", and if I want to go down to a floor it would output "6 5 4 3 2 1". Here is my code currently:

```
public class SmartElevator {

    int currentFloor = 1;
    boolean inServiceMode = false;

    public void goToFloor(int floor) {
        if (floor >= 1 && floor <= 20)   
            if (inServiceMode == false) {
                System.out.println();
                currentFloor = floor;
            } else {
                System.out.println("SERVICE MODE");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you at least tried doing it? What's the concrete problem?

Comment: Following the other question you posted, You know about loop, so you're able to do it, just write the 2 lines missing : the loop + the print

Comment: use `for-each` loop for looping

Comment: Just in case this is some kind of application-test (the famous *elevator test*), make sure you are allowed to ask for help like this. The company might find this thread and then you might don't get the position. If that does not apply to you, please ignore the comment.

Comment: @Deadpool and on what ? There is no structure/iterable to do on

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
int currentFloor = 1;
boolean inServiceMode = false;

public void goToFloor(int floor) {
    if (floor >= 1 && floor <= 20) {
        if (inServiceMode == false) {

            if (currentFloor < floor) {
                // We are going up
                for (int i = currentFloor + 1; i <= floor; i++) {
                    System.out.println("^ Floor: " + i);
                }
            } else {
                // We are going down
                for (int i = currentFloor - 1; i >= floor; i--) {
                    System.out.println("v Floor: " + i);
                }
            }

            currentFloor = floor;
        } else {
            System.out.println("SERVICE MODE");
        }
    }
}
```

---

With code:

```
goToFloor(10);

goToFloor(2);

goToFloor(12);
```

The output is:

```
^ Floor: 2
^ Floor: 3
^ Floor: 4
^ Floor: 5
^ Floor: 6
^ Floor: 7
^ Floor: 8
^ Floor: 9
^ Floor: 10
v Floor: 9
v Floor: 8
v Floor: 7
v Floor: 6
v Floor: 5
v Floor: 4
v Floor: 3
v Floor: 2
^ Floor: 3
^ Floor: 4
^ Floor: 5
^ Floor: 6
^ Floor: 7
^ Floor: 8
^ Floor: 9
^ Floor: 10
^ Floor: 11
^ Floor: 12
```